# Extract Filebeat prospector path regexp match to field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I wonder if there's anyway to extract regexp match of Filebeat prospector path to a field, for ex. something like:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/logs/apps/[(a-z)]/*.log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: log
  fields:
    log_topic: "app-${1}"
```

so the log_topic field will be "app-myAppName" assuming the directory of the log file was myAppName.

How can I extract the matched pattern from the regular expression in the paths?

Comment: The absolute path of the file the log event came from is exported in the `source` field of the event, you can trivially extract just the filename from this field once youre processing in logstash

Comment: Since the paths are globs and not really regular expressions I'm fairly certain this cannot be done

Comment: If you have Logstash in the pipeline, you can do this using grok.

Comment: @sammy, yes I have Logstash in my pipeline and I can do that using grok, but I want to make the Separation on Kafka also and not only on the ELK

Comment: Same question as you. Comment to mark this question.